# Concurrent build within Docker with regards to multi staging

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose

I have a monolithic repo that contains all of my projects. The current setup I have is to bring up a build container, mount my monolithic repo, and build my projects sequentially. Copy out the binaries, and build their respective runtime (production) containers sequentially.

I find this process quite slow and want to improve the speed. Two main **approach** I want to take is

1. Within the build container, build my project binaries concurrently. Instead of sequentially.
2. Like step 1, also build my runtime (production) containers concurrently.

I did some research and it seems like there are two Docker **features** that are of my interest:

1. [Multi-stage building](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Which allows me to skip worrying about the build container and put everything into one `Dockerfiles`.
2. [`--parallel`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) option for `docker-compose`, which would solve **approach** #2, allowing me to build my runtime containers concurrently.

However, there's still two main **issues**:

1. How do I glue the two **features** together?
2. How do I build my binaries concurrently inside the build Docker? In other words, how can I achieve **approach** #1?

### Clarifications

Regardless of whether multi-stage is used or not, there's two logical phases.

First is the binary building phase. During this phase, the artifacts are the compiled executables (binaries) from the build containers. Since I'm not using multi-stage build, I'm copying these binaries out to the host, so the host serves as an intermediate staging area. Currently, the binaries are being built sequentially, I want to build them concurrently inside the build container. Hence **approach** #1.

Second is the image building phase. During this phase, the binaries from the previous phase, which are now stored on the host, are used to built my production images. I also want to build these images concurrently, hence **approach** #2.

Multi-stage allows me to eliminate the need for an intermedia staging area (the host). And `--parallel` allows me to build the production images concurrently.

What I'm wondering is how I can achieve **approach** #1 & #2 using multi-stage and `--parallel`. Because for every project, I can define a separate multi-stage `Dockerfiles` and call `--parallel` on all of them to have their images built separately. This would achieve **approach** #2, but this would spawn a separate build container for each project and take up a lot of resource (I use the same build container for all my projects and it's 6 GB). On the other hand, I can write a script to build my project binaries concurrently inside the build container. This would achieve **approach** #1, but then I can't use multi-stage if I want to build the production images concurrently.

What I really want is a `Dockerfiles` like this:

```
FROM alpine:latest AS builder
RUN concurrent_build.sh binary_a binary_b

FROM builder AS prod_img_a
COPY binary_a .

FROM builder AS prod_img_b
COPY binary_b .
```

And be able to run a `docker-compose` command like this (I'm making this up):

```
docker-compose --parallel prod_img_a prod_img_b
```

### Further clarifications

The run-time binaries and run-time containers are not separate things. I just want to be able to parallel build the binaries AND the production images.

`--parallel` does not use different hosts, but my build container is huge. If I use multi-stage build and running something like 15 of these build containers in parallel on my local dev machine could be bad.

I'm thinking about compiling the binary and run-time containers separately too but I'm not finding an easy way to do that. I have never used `docker commit`, would that sacrifice docker cache?

Comment: I don't think I understand how a multi-stage build fits in here. Each Docker project can have multi-stage builds, but that is not the same as parallelisation. It seems to me that if you are looking to build images in parallel, `--parallel` solves this issue.

Comment: I wonder if what I have not fully understood is what "project binaries" are. Are these a run-time artefact that is different to the run-time image? What are they? I wonder if what you are asking about is how to obtain the binary from inside each parallel image build?

Comment: Does every Dockerfile product a run-time image _and_ a binary?

Comment: OK, that is a bit clearer, thanks. Why are run-time binaries and run-time containers separate things? It seems to me that if you have a binary that runs in a container, you can just create the container. Are you separating them out so you can create the binary and the container at the same time, and then finally copy the binary into the container?

Comment: How long does binary building and container building take, approximately? It is worth considering whether the engineering effort to achieve better parallelisation is worth the time, complexity and potential pipeline brittleness involved.

Comment: Does `--parallel` use different hosts, or does it just rely on the fact that some build processes are network bound, and thus there is spare CPU resource available on the one host? (My Docker Compose is rather too old to have it!)

Comment: I am thinking that you could compile your binary compilation containers and run-time containers separately (all in parallel) without using multi-stage. When everything is built in parallel, you can spin all containers up (binary and runtime) and copy the binaries from the compile containers to the runtime containers. Finally you can use `docker commit` to create new runtime containers containing the binaries. If you think that approach might be helpful, I will write an answer about it.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't have to use `--parallel` if you don't want to (that may not give you enough control about the amount of parallelisation). You could instead just do your `docker build` commands with the background flag `&` so you do two or three at a time, for example - you don't want to overload your system to the degree that parallelisation causes the server to run out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are several things to try here. Firstly, yes, do try `--parallel`, it would be interesting to see the effect on your overall build times. It looks like you have no control over the number of parallel builds though, so I wonder if it would try to do them all in one go.

If you find that it does, you could write `docker-compose.yml` files that only contain a subset of your services, such that you only have five at a time, and then build against each one in turn. Indeed, you could write a script that reads your existing YAML config and splits it up, so that you do not need to maintain your overall config and your split-up configs separately.

I suggested in the comments that multi-stage would not help, but I think now that this is not the case. I was wondering whether the second stage in a Dockerfile would block until the first one is completed, but this should not be so - if the second stage starts from a known image then it should only block when it encounters a `COPY --from=first_stage` command, which you can do right at the end, when you copy your binary from the compilation stage.

Of course, if it is the case that multi-stage builds are not parallelised, then `docker commit` would be worth a try. You've asked whether this uses the layer cache, and the answer is I don't think it matters - your operation here would thus:

- Spin up the binary container to run a shell or a sleep command
- Spin up the runtime container in the same way
- Use `docker cp` to copy the binary from the first one to the second one
- Use `docker commit` to create a new runtime image from the new runtime container

This does not involve any network operations, and so should be pretty quick - you will have benefited greatly from the parallelisation already at this point. If the binaries are of non-trivial size, you could even try parallelising your copy operations:

```
docker cp binary1:/path/to/binary runtime1:/path/to/binary &
docker cp binary2:/path/to/binary runtime2:/path/to/binary &
docker cp binary3:/path/to/binary runtime3:/path/to/binary &
```

Note though these are disk-bound operations, so you may find there is no advantage over doing them serially.

Could you give this a go and report back on:

- your existing build times per container
- your existing build times overall
- your new build times after parallelisation

Do it all locally to start off with, and if you get some useful speed-up, try it on your build infrastructure, where you are likely to have more CPU cores.

Comment: The current build is broken. It uses `git diff` to try and mimic caching, but it doesn't work correctly and it's too difficult to fix. So I might not be able to report back about existing build, but I will try the new builds mentioned and report back.

Comment: OK, no worries @thestateofmay. That part does not matter too much - I though it would just be interesting to see how much time is saved with parallelisation.

Comment: (Perhaps you could obtain some approximate times from back when your build worked, so that you can determine whether the parallelisation work results in a worthwhile speed improvement).

Comment: will do! Perhaps I can do a clean system clean without the `git diff` and compare. Although it would be a bit of an unfair comparison.

Comment: Ok I'm back. I updated the question with some performance results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries @thestateofmay, nice work. Would you move that to an answer? Posting a self-answer is most welcome here, and helps differentiate your answer material from the original question.

Answer (score 4):

**Results**

My mono-repo containers 16 projects, some are micro services being a few MBs, some are bigger services that are about 300 to 500 MBs.

The build contains the compilation of two prerequisites, one is `gRPC`, and the other is `XDR`. both are trivially small, taking only 1 or 2 seconds to build.

The build contains a `node_modules` installation phase. NPM install and build is THE bottleneck of the project and by far the slowest.

The strategy I am using is to split the build into two stages:

1. First stage is to spin up a monolithic build docker, mount the mono-repo to it with `cache` consistency as a binding volume. And build all of my container's binary dependencies inside of it in parallel using Goroutines. Each Goroutine is calling a build.sh bash script that does the building. The resulting binaries are written to the same mounted volume. There is cache being used in the form of a mounted docker volume, and the binaries are preserved across runs to a best effort.
2. Second stage is to build the images in parallel. This is done using docker's Go SDK documented [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client). This is also done in parallel using Goroutines. Nothing else is special about this stage besides some basic optimizations.

I do not have performance data about the old build system, but building all 16 projects easily took the upper bound of 30 minutes. This build was extremely basic and did not build the images in parallel or use any optimizations.

The new build is extremely fast. If everything is cached and there's no changes, then the build takes ~2 minutes. In other words, the overhead of bring up the build system, checking the cache, and building the same cached docker images takes ~2 minutes. If there's no cache at all, the new build takes ~5 minutes. A HUGE improvement from the old build.

Thanks to @halfer for the help.